# Reduce Hash Values

Tags: ruby, hash, reduce

I am having trouble with the syntax for reduce.  I have a hash of the following format:

```
H = {"Key1" => 1, "Key2" => 2}
```

I would like to use reduce to find the sum of the values in this function.

Something Like

```
H.reduce(0) {|memo, elem| memo+=elem}
```

I know this is wrong.  I dont understand how I can make elem the value of the hash.

Comment: Try: H.values.reduce(:+)

Answer (score 42, accepted):

Use [`Enumerable#reduce`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Enumerable.html#method-i-reduce), if you're ok with getting `nil` if the hash happens to be empty:

```ruby
H.values.reduce(:+) # => 3
Hash.new.values.reduce(:+) # => nil
```

To safely get `0` when the hash is empty, use:

```ruby
H.values.reduce(0) { |sum,x| sum + x } # or...
H.reduce(0) { |sum,(key,val)| sum + val } # ...if you need to inspect the key
```

Here's a quick benchmark, for kicks.  Note that it appears to be slightly faster to reduce just the values rather than values from the key/value pairs:

```
                               user     system      total        real
H.values.reduce(:+)        4.510000   0.080000   4.590000 (  4.595229)
H.values.reduce(0) {...}   4.660000   0.080000   4.740000 (  4.739708)
H.reduce(0) {...}          5.160000   0.070000   5.230000 (  5.241916)
```

```ruby
require 'benchmark'

size = 1_000
hash = Hash[* Array.new(size*2) { rand } ]

N=10_000
Benchmark.bm(24) do |x|
  x.report('H.values.reduce(:+)')      { N.times { hash.dup.values.reduce(:+) } }
  x.report('H.values.reduce(0) {...}') { N.times { hash.dup.values.reduce(0) { |sum,x| sum + x } } }
  x.report('H.reduce(0) {...}')        { N.times { hash.dup.reduce(0) { |sum,(_,v)| sum + v } } }
end
```

Comment: Note that this doesn't return 0 if a hash is empty. You'd need to use the memo version below

Answer (score 87):

You can make `elem` contain the value by splitting it up in 2 variables:

```
H.reduce(0) {|memo, (key, val)| memo + val}
```

Comment: I would have written `memo + val` to avoid letting people think that updating `memo` is helpful.

Comment: Strongly agreeing with @lkuty, the += mutation of memo is unnecessary and misleading.

Answer (score 6):

Try this:

```
H.reduce(0) { |memo, elem| memo += elem[1] }
```

or

```
H.reduce(0) { |memo, (key, value)| memo += value }
```

Comment: I would have written `memo + value` to avoid letting people think that updating `memo` is helpful.

Answer (score 2):

I know I'm excavating this one, but if you happen to use Rails, the [`.sum` method](http://apidock.com/rails/v4.2.1/Enumerable/sum) can help:

```
H = {"Key1" => 1, "Key2" => 2}
=> {"Key1"=>1, "Key2"=>2}
> H.values.sum
=> 3
```

Advantage is that it returns `0` on empty hashes:

```
> {}.values.sum
=> 0
> {}.values.reduce(:+)
=> nil
```

I noticed it was Rails-specific only after typing this answer. I know the OP didn't add the Rails tag, but I figured it might be useful for people stopping by.

Note that as of Ruby 2.4.0, [`.sum` is now available](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-sum).

Comment: `.sum` is now implemented in Ruby 2.4 [Enumerable#sum](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-sum).

Answer (score 1):

```
h = {"Key1" => 1, "Key2" => 2}

h.values.inject(0){|f,v| f += v.to_i }
# => 3
```

or

```
h.values.inject(:+)
# => 3
```

Answer (score 0):

In case of a complex hash it might be easier to map it first to an array of values, then reduce:

```
values = H.map do |k, v|
    # some complex logic here
end
values.reduce(:+)
```

Or `values.reduce(0, :+)` if the array might be empty.