# How to find the list of pairs in an array using ruby?

Tags: ruby

**Input**:

```
a = [4, 5, 5, 5, 6, 6, 4, 1, 4, 4, 3, 6, 6, 3, 6, 1, 4, 5, 5, 5]
```

How to list out no of pairs in an array.

**Output:**

**9**

**Description**

```
#no 1(1 pair)
#no 3(1 pair)
#no 4(2 pairs)
#no 5(3 pairs)
#no 6(2 pairs)
#so total 9 pairs
```

Comment: What pairs are you considering? All combinations of 2 elements? Or just adjacent pairs? Also, your subject says "uniq pairs" but your question doesn't mention unique. Which is it?

Comment: All combinations or 2 elements.

Comment: If you find it helpful.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35585399/frequency-of-pairs-in-an-array-ruby

Comment: added expected output

Comment: The title asks for the *number* of unique pairs. In the body you ask for a *list* of such pairs. Which is it? Please show the 9 unique pairs that is the desired result for your example. For example, you say "#no 5(3 pairs)". What are those 3 pairs?

Comment: [1, 1, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6] in this array you can see the pairs list

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is another option:

```
a.group_by(&:itself).transform_values{ |v| v.size / 2 }.values.sum
#=> 9
```

---

**How it works.**

First group the elements by value:

```
a.group_by(&:itself) #=> {4=>[4, 4, 4, 4, 4], 5=>[5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5], 6=>[6, 6, 6, 6, 6], 1=>[1, 1], 3=>[3, 3]}
```

Then transforming the keys to the pair count:

```
a.group_by(&:itself).transform_values{ |v| v.size / 2 } #=> {4=>2, 5=>3, 6=>2, 1=>1, 3=>1}
```

So, get the values of the hash:

```
a.group_by(&:itself).transform_values{ |v| v.size / 2 }.values #=> [2, 3, 2, 1, 1]
```

Finally, sum the values, which is the first line of code posted above.

Answer (score 1):

```
arr = [4, 5, 5, 5, 6, 6, 4, 1, 4, 4, 3, 6, 6, 3, 6, 1, 4, 5, 5, 5]
hash = Hash.new(0)
arr.each { |e| hash[e] += 1 }
hash.values.reduce(0) { |s, n| s += n / 2 } // => 9
```

Since from what I can gather you are basically removing integers the moment they got paired once so technically it's just an integer division by two.

[1] [How to count identical string elements in a Ruby array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5128200/how-to-count-identical-string-elements-in-a-ruby-array)

[2] [Reduce Hash Values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13882956/reduce-hash-values)

Comment: Good answer. OP has edited title so the total number (9) is no longer asked for, so you might write `arr.each_with_object(Hash.new(0)) { |e,hash| hash[e] += 1 }.transform_values { |v| v/2 } #=> {4=>2, 5=>3, 6=>2, 1=>1, 3=>1}`.

Answer (score 1):

I have done like this, It works

```
  b = []
  a.uniq.each { |i| b.push(a.count(i)/2)}
  b.sum
```

Comment: Note that `count` has to traverse the entire array each time which makes this solution rather inefficient.